# Check if current time is between 2 times in different Timezone

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Need to find if the user visiting my page is between support hours 8:00am or 16:00pm PST, So if an user from Asia or other Timezone visit the page outside of those hours get a custom label, I can make it work for not timezone involved but I'm having problems with timezone, and the following code always is returning true. any ideas how to achieve this?

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-timezone';

const timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
const supportStartTime = moment().tz(timezone).hours(8).minutes(0).seconds(0);
const supportEndsTime = moment().tz(timezone).hours(16).minutes(0).seconds(0);

const now = moment();
const isBetweenWorkingHours = now.isBetween(supportStartTime,supportEndsTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working fine:

```
var timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
var supportStartTime = moment().tz(timezone).hours(8).minutes(0).seconds(0);
console.log(supportStartTime.format());
var supportEndsTime = moment().tz(timezone).hours(16).minutes(0).seconds(0);
console.log(supportEndsTime.format());

var now = moment().tz('EST').startOf('day').hours(10);
console.log(now.format());
var isBetweenWorkingHours = now.isBetween(supportStartTime,supportEndsTime);
console.log(isBetweenWorkingHours);

var now = moment().tz('EST').startOf('day').hours(12);
console.log(now.format());
var isBetweenWorkingHours = now.isBetween(supportStartTime,supportEndsTime);
console.log(isBetweenWorkingHours);

var now = moment();
console.log(now.format());
var isBetweenWorkingHours = now.isBetween(supportStartTime,supportEndsTime);
console.log(isBetweenWorkingHours);
```

Which produces:

```
2016-11-06T08:00:00-08:00
2016-11-06T16:00:00-08:00
2016-11-06T10:00:00-05:00
false
2016-11-06T12:00:00-05:00
true
2016-11-06T15:22:48-08:00
true
```

(I'm in pacific time which is why the time zone comes out that way on the last item.)

---

```
console.log(moment().format());
console.log(moment().tz('EST').format());
console.log(moment().tz('UTC').format());
```

produces:

```
2016-11-06T16:24:53-08:00
2016-11-06T19:24:53-05:00
2016-11-07T00:24:53Z
```

These are all the same "now". If you were in EST and ran `moment().format()`, you'd get the current time with your timezone attached (line 2). If somebody in UTC ran `moment().format()` simultaneously, they'd get "now" relative to their own time zone (line 3). They're both the same "now" since they were run simultaneously, they just have different local representations.

Comment: I think my problem is that I can't initialize `now` with a predefined timezone, maybe using moment.tz.guess(), be a solution?

Comment: @ncubica The whole point of `moment` and `moment-timezone` is to let you ignore time zones and other difficulties with calculating human datetimes. Using `moment()` gives you an object that represents that instant in time, regardless of timezone. Using `tz()` just lets you use other functions on that object in that time zone's context. `.inBetween()` doesn't need any further help because of this.